# How can I use AWS Glue to start with data pulled from web service endpoints?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

More source data comes from an Web Service endpoint that I need to poll periodically.  Once I get the data, I can perform traditional ETL using pyspark and eventually write the data to S3 and Redshift.

I'm not sure how to do that initial extraction or even what I should be looking for in the AWS Glue docs.  Can a "source" web service end point be considered a table with regard to the Data Catalog?

Any examples would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that a 'source' webservice endpoint can be considered a table in the Glue Data Catalog.  But, it shouldn't be too difficult to get this to work.

1. Setup something to poll this Web Service endpoint periodically to retrieve the data you are after.  The data polled should be placed into an S3 'source' bucket/location.
2. Setup a Table in the Glue Data Catalog that describes the data that is being polled from step 1.  Depending on what this data looks like, you may be able to use a Crawler to create the table, but I have had better experiences with creating my tables manually (initially, and eventually with CloudFormation).
3. Use the Job Creation Wizard (via `Add Job` button in the Jobs view) to create the job, following the prompts.  The important part here is to make sure you set your 'source' as the table setup in step 2.
4. After creating the job, you will be able to modify the script (either Python or Scala) to apply the ETL of your choosing.

[This page from the AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/author-job.html) does a pretty good job of describing the process with a bit more detail.

Comment: I have a better understanding now of what the Data Catalog means; and I see that adding a web service doesn't really make sense.

Your solution sounds good. In my case, though, because the data is not really that big, I'm going to kick off the export from an Amazon Lambda and then arrange for another Lambda callback to be hit when it's done.  Essentially I'll do that data extraction and write the data to S3 before even starting any job in Glue.  From there, it should be a traditional Glue ETL job.