# SOAP API request using AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, soap, aws-glue

Is it possible to make SOAP API requests using AWS Glue to extract data from external webservices such as ViewPoint for Projects ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use AWS Glue to start with data pulled from web service endpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930845/how-can-i-use-aws-glue-to-start-with-data-pulled-from-web-service-endpoints)

Comment: How do I set up the web service to pass data to the S3 bucket?  I am a complete beginner in handling API's and AWS services

Comment: Because you are new to AWS and APIs, start at the basics. See this Topic in the AWS Java Dev guide to learn how to interact with Amazon S3 using an API.... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html